# SQLite- button adds value to db.query

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-intent, android-sqlite

I've got a database with the following columns:

`Book_name`, `book_id`, `chapter_number`, `chapter_id`, `line_number`, `line_id`

I'm doing this app to read books, select a chapter to read, and then display all the lines.

First `listview` displays all the books, when the user selects on a book name, it passes the book_id to display all the chapters under that book, when selecting a chapter, it passes the `chapter_id` to display all the lines under that chapter.

My question is, when a user is busy reading they must press the back button to display all the chapters again and then select the next chapter. I want to put a button on the `listview` displaying all the lines (after the chapter has been selected) for the user to press and then it should basically re-query the db to display the next available chapter.

Each `listview` is in it's own activity and id's gets passed with Intents.

I don't know what code you guys want to see so please just ask.

This is the **list** in `DBHandler2` for the chapters:

```
public List<defineBybeldbAlles> getListHoofstuk(String boek_id_na_hoofstuk){
        defineBybeldbAlles defineBybeldbHoofstuk = null;
        List<defineBybeldbAlles> defineBybeldbAllesList = new ArrayList<>();
        opendatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PWLBybel WHERE " + COLUMN_BOEK_ID + " = '" + boek_id_na_hoofstuk + "'GROUP BY hoofstuk_id ORDER BY hoofstuk_id * 1 ASC", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            defineBybeldbHoofstuk = new defineBybeldbAlles(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getInt(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getInt(5),cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7),cursor.getInt(8),cursor.getString(9),cursor.getString(10));
            defineBybeldbAllesList.add(defineBybeldbHoofstuk);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return defineBybeldbAllesList;
}
```

This is **where I pass** the `chapter_id` **in my chapter activity** to diplay the lines in **the lines activity**:

```
 public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3){

                    //on selecting a hoofstk
                    //BybelActivityVers will be launched to show verse inside
                    Intent hoofstukIntent = new Intent(BybelActivityHoofstuk.this,BybelActivityVers.class);

                    //send hoofstuk_id to VersActivity to get verse under that book
                    String hoofstuk_id_na_vers = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hoofstuk_id)).getText().toString();
                    hoofstukIntent.putExtra("hoofstuk_id", hoofstuk_id_na_vers);

                    String hoofstuk_nommer_na_vers = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.custom_row_hoofstuktext)).getText().toString();
                    hoofstukIntent.putExtra("custom_row_hoofstuktext", hoofstuk_nommer_na_vers);

                    startActivity(hoofstukIntent);
                }
            });
```

Now this is the **list** in `DBHandler3` for the lines:

```
public List<defineBybeldbAlles> getListVers(String hoofstuk_id_na_vers){
        defineBybeldbAlles defineBybeldbVers = null;
        List<defineBybeldbAlles> defineBybeldbVersList = new ArrayList<>();
        opendatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PWLBybel WHERE " + COLUMN_HOOFSTUK_ID + " = '" + hoofstuk_id_na_vers + "'GROUP BY vers_id ORDER BY vers_id * 1 ASC", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            defineBybeldbVers = new defineBybeldbAlles(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getInt(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getInt(5),cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7),cursor.getInt(8),cursor.getString(9),cursor.getString(10));
            defineBybeldbVersList.add(defineBybeldbVers);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return defineBybeldbVersList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set variable chapterid + 1 in current chapter to be passed in intent 
Then `Intent i = new intent(PARAMETERS);
finish();
startactivity(i);`
Then run the query with db to get details of new chapter in new intent 
Its working thanks

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how it would look like within my current code please, I'm not an expert sorry

Answer (score 0):

In your ques add a button .
  check if list is scrolled to last

```
'
 mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (mListView.getAdapter() == null)
            return ;

        if (mListView.getAdapter().getCount() == 0)
            return ;

        int l = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;
        if (l >= totalItemCount && !isLoading) {
            // It is time to add new data. We call the listener
            isLoading = true;

        }
    }
});
```

'

when is loading is true dat means ur list is at its last
and then make nextbutton.setvisibility(View.Visible);
and on click of button
get ur chapter id and add 1 to it *i.e.. next chapter id*
and start intent and pass chapter and page id with dat intent like
`Intent i = new Intent(this,Currentclass.java);
finish();
start activity(i);`
// your page will be changed now
please tick the answer as correct thanks:)

Comment: I've already got a button on the screen, I want it stationary so there's no need to display it at the end of the list (As long as its at the bottom). I don't see how I can change the list with your answer, shouldn't the button change the query from the previous activity?